# Error: No matching asm pattern exists

Tags: c, assembly, simulink, low-level

Writing in C in ASCET (ASCET is like SIMULINK).

External Source is

```
asm uint32 HAL_GetTB(uint16 reg);
uint32 HAL_GetTimeBase(uint16 reggy);

uint32 HAL_GetTimeBase(uint16 reggy)
{
    uint32 rtn;
    rtn = HAL_GetTB(reggy);
    return(rtn);    
}

asm uint32 HAL_GetTB(uint16 reg)
{
GetTimebaseVal:
    mfspr   r3, reg
}
```

Header is:

```
#define TIMEBASELOWREAD   268
#define TIMEBASEHIGHREAD   269

extern  uint32 HAL_GetTimeBase(uint16 reggy);
```

The two modules of C code are :

```
uint32 TBH;

TBH = HAL_GetTimeBase(TIMEBASEHIGHREAD);
return(TBH);
```

and:

```
uint32 TBL;

TBL = HAL_GetTimeBase(TIMEBASELOWREAD);
return(TBL);
```

Coding on Freescale MPC5674 (Fixed Point) for RTA(active) with object base controller Arithmetic and Implicit Implementation

I am very confused as to the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
asm uint32 HAL_GetTB(uint16 reg)
{
GetTimebaseVal:
    mfspr   r3, reg
}
```

should be:

```
asm uint32 HAL_GetTB(uint16 sprreg)
{
% reg sprreg;
! "r3"
GetTimebaseVal:
    mfspr   r3, sprreg
}
```